# Load XML file into object. Best method?

Tags: xsd, xml-serialization, poco

We are receiving an XML file from our client. I want to load the data from this file into a class, but am unsure about which way to go about it.

I have an XSD to defining what is expected in the XML file, so therefore i can easily validate the XML file.

Can i use the XSD file to load the data into a POCO, using some sort of serialization?

The other way i was thinking was to load the xml into a XMLDocument and use XPath to populate each property in my class.

Cheers for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complex the XSD is, you have a couple of options:

- Use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx) to generate C# classes which can be used in conjunction with the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).
- Use [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) with the `/dconly` argument to generate [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)-attributed types appropriate for use with the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).